# Get coordinates of head in Kinect

Tags: kinect

i am making an App in Open GL (C++) with Kinect.

I want to get the coordinates of head (Skeleton).

I saw the function:

`void CSkeletalViewerApp::Nui_DrawSkeletonSegment( NUI_SKELETON_DATA * pSkel, int numJoints, ... )` ,

but I dont know how to use it and extract the coordinates of the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the code snipped you posted, we can assume you are using Microsoft's Kinect for Windows SDK.

The coordinates of the joints are stored in the SkeletonPositions member of the [`NUI_SKELETON_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/nuiskeleton.nui_skeleton_data.aspx) structure. Instances of this structure can be found in the SkeletonData member of the [`NUI_SKELETON_FRAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/nuiskeleton.nui_skeleton_frame.aspx) structure, which is provided whenever the skeleton tracking engine finishes tracking.

Of course, this will only work, if the sensor is initialized properly. Please have a look at the sample projects that come with the SDK, and read Microsoft's online documentation.

Also, be aware that the Kinect's coordinate system has its origin at the sensor and provides coordinate values ranging roughly from -2.2 to 2.2 on the x-axis, from -1.6 to 1.6 on the y-axis, and from 0.0 to 4.0 on the z-axis (depth). Thus, you might need to apply some transformations.

Comment: What transformations? How do I achieve them?

Comment: I suggested translating the plane coordinates (x, y) by (-2.2, -1.6). This step is not absolutely necessary, but it makes mapping Kinect coordinates to screen coordinates easier.